# How to unpack a tuple from left to right?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Is there a clean/simple way to unpack a Python tuple on the right hand side from left to right?

For example for

```
j = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

v,b,n = j[4:7]
```

Can I modify the slice notation so that `v = j[6], b=j[5], n=j[4]` ?

I realise I can just order the left side to get the desired element but there might be instances where I would just want to unpack the tuple from left to right I think.

Comment: Why would you not just reorder the left side?

Comment: If you wish to reverse arbitrary sequences for assignment, `v,b,n = reversed(my_values)` will do. For example, a `collections.deque` cannot be reversed by slice notation.

Comment: You can simply reverse the list and slice it accordingly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case you want to keep the original indices (i.e. don't want to bother with changing 4 and 7 to 6 and 3) you can also use:

```
v, b, n = (j[4:7][::-1])
```

Comment: This works as well thank you for your help.  The index of the last element with value 7 is [6] and in yours we range from [4] inclusive to [7] not included.  In Moses' answer I think it is similar but ranges from [6] inclusive down to [3] not included.  So it seems they both access the same indices and the solution provided by Mosses a bit cleaner I think.  Thanks

Answer (score 51):

This should do:

```
v,b,n = j[6:3:-1]
```

A step value of `-1` starting at `6`

Comment: Thanks so much that did it.  I tried the same but as an absolute beginner had tried [3:6:-1] not understanding the start stop index needed to be reversed as well

Comment: @AnthonyLeeMeier You can also have a look at this thread on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: I think maybe `v, b, n = j[:-4:-1]` is better, since it's agnostic about the length of `j`.

Answer (score 10):

```
 n,b,v=j[4:7]
```

will also work.  You can just change the order or the returned unpacked values

Comment: *I realise I can just order the left side to get the desired element*

Answer (score 9):

You could ignore the first after reversing and use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
j = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7


_, v, b, n, *_ = reversed(j)

print(v, b, n)
```

Which would give you:

```
6 5 4
```

Or if you want to get arbitrary elements you could use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
j = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

from operator import itemgetter


def unpack(it, *args):
    return itemgetter(*args)(it)

v,b,n = unpack(j, -2,-3,-4)

print(v, b, n)
```

The advantage of *itemgetter* is it will work on any iterable and the elements don't have to be consecutive.

Comment: Well, you can also do `v, b, n = reversed(j[4:7])` without using extended unpacking. this has the benefit that if `j` is long 10 million items the interpreter doesn't have to create new list containing all the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

-1 mean looking from reverse, with last 3rd element to last element

```
>>> v,b,n=j[-1:-4:-1]
>>> print 'v=',v,'b=',b,'n=',n
v= 7 b= 6 n= 5
>>>
```