# An elegant way to slice a list given another list of ids to slice from

Tags: python, slice

I am looking for an elegant way to slice a list `l` in python, given a list of ids `l_ids`.
For example, instead of writing

```
new_list = [l[i] for i in l_ids]
```

Write something like (Pseudo code):

```
new_list = l[*l_ids]
```

Is there a similar way to slice lists?

I have the feeling that someone have asked that already, but I couldn't find any reference for it.

**Edit:** It is OK to assume that all the list items are of the same type?

Comment: itemgetter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276068/unpack-a-python-tuple-from-left-to-right/38276396#38276396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the list elements are of the same type, it is possible to use numpy:

```
from numpy import *
new_list = array(l)[l_ids]
```

Comment: If you are using numpy then it is quite a different question

Comment: numpy is a package as operator (with itemgetter) is. I don't see a problem if it provides a useful and concise solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter(*items)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

getter = itemgetter(*lst_ids)
new_list = list(getter(lst))
```

Also, note that I renamed `l` variable to `lst` because it is less ambiguous and [should be avoided](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid).

You can implicitly cast the tuple to a list using Python 3 unpacking, as @JonClements commented:

```
*new_list, = getter(lst)
```

Finally, since Python 3.5, you can also use extended unpacking:

```
new_list = [*getter(lst)]
```

Comment: If you're going to mention the extended unpacking in 3.5, don't forget that there's other unpacking that'll work in the 3 series (although it's not very pretty) `*new_lst, = getter(lst)` (and since `list()` will work across the board and says what it means - I'd stick with that anyway...)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html)

```
from operator import itemgetter

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l_ids = [1, 2, 3]
list(itemgetter(*l_ids)(l))
```

> ['b', 'c', 'd']

Answer (score 2):

I don't think importing anything is particularly elegant, or pythonic.

List comprehensions work, and I can't see a reason not to use them (or no good reason to import something to do the same thing):

```
>>> x = [3,5,7,0,1,4,2,6]
>>> y = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
>>> nList = [y[i] for i in x]
>>> nList
['d', 'f', 'h', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'g']
```

The list comprehension is doing the following:

```
indexes = [3,5,7,0,1,4,2,6]
data = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
nList = []
for index in indexes:
    nList += [data[index]]
```

The comprehension looks pretty pythonic and elegant to me.

Comment: If the author only need to create such a list once, I think list comprehension is perfectly fine, but `itemgetter()` it a elegant way if it needs to be repeated several times.

Comment: @Delgan Ahh, good point. I guess if you have the same list of ids for multiple data lists, it's slower.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with *itemgetter* but you could also *map* *list.__getitem_*_:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l_ids = [1, 2, 3]

new = list(map(l.__getitem__, l_ids))
```

Comment: I am not sure method with double leadind and trailing underscore should be used, it is reserved to Python internally, is not it?

Comment: It is a matter of opinion, I and lots of other people often use the same logic to avoid having to use lambda calls with map, filters i.e some_set.__contains__ vs lambda st: x in st etc..